# Questions on Haskell's sequence function

Tags: haskell, monads

I've been going through UPenn's CS194 and currently on Lecture 7, Monads. I thought I was getting an okay handle on Monads until I saw the implementation of the sequence function and started poking around.

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence [] = return []
sequence (ma:mas) = do
  a  <- ma
  as <- sequence mas
  return (a:as)
```

This seems intuitive at first glance, but as I delved into it, I came up against a bunch of questions:

1. The type of `return []` is : `return [] :: Monad m => m [t]` . Earlier in the same lesson, the `Monad` instance for `[]` defines return as:  `return x = [x]`.  How did this lead to the type signature `m [t]` for `return []`?
2. `a <- ma` . What is type of `a` here, assuming I called sequence with `[Just 5, Just 9]` ?  By the `Monad` instance definition of `Maybe`:

   ```
   Just x  >>= k = k x
   ```

   I would think `x`, or `a` in the case of `sequence` would be a `Num`. But it must really be a `Monad` of `Num`. How did `x` become a monad of `Num` here when `Just x` from the instance definition of `Maybe` seems to be pulling `x` out of `Just`?

Comment: here `return []` is not `\ x -> [x]` as in the monad instance for `[]` - it's the `return` function from the `m` monad (so the result will depend on what `m` really is) - think `m = Maybe` if it helps you - so `return []` would be `Just []`

Comment: 2.) if you call `sequence [Just 5, Just 9]` then the type of a will be some `Num` yes (`a`will be `5` and `9`) - and there is no "Monad" in the `Num`/`5` - you could say it`s in `Just` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `return []` is `Monad m => m [t]` - here, the `[]` is an instance of `[t]`, i.e. a list of some arbitrary type (the type is arbitrary since it's the empty list, so there are no instances of the type anyway). If you substitute the list monad, the type of `return` is `t -> [t]`, and `return []` yields `[[]]`. The confusing thing is that both the monad and the contained value are lists.

The type of `return` in general is `Monad m => t -> m t`. If you specialize for lists, you get `t -> [t]`, so the list type takes the place of `m`. The special syntax for lists makes this a bit more confusing; if you use the maybe monad instead, specialized return has the type `t -> Maybe t`, so you can see clearly how the `m` was replaced by `Maybe`. In the maybe monad, the type of `return []` is `Maybe [t]`: the monad now wraps some list.

The type of `return []` is `Monad m => m [t]`, a list wrapped by the monad. If you use the list monad, you substitute the `m` with the list constructor and get `[[t]]`, which is the right type.

As for the second question, why do you think that `a` must be a monad?

**Edit after clarification in comment**

In the example call `sequence [Just 5, Just 9]` you gave, the monad is maybe, not list; that list is an ordinary list as required by the type of `sequence`. Remember that it takes a `[m a]` as input. As you supply a `Num a => [Maybe a]` as input, that makes the monad `Maybe`, and the result type is `Num a => Maybe [a]`. `sequence` turns a list of optional values into an optional list. This means that in the first case of `sequence`, the `return []` applies to `Maybe`'s `return` and means `Just []`. This makes sense, as calling `sequence []` in the maybe monad should return `Just []`.

Now, in the do-block of the second case, we have a bunch of variables, and it helps to figure out the type of each. I'll do that for the concrete case of `Maybe` and `Int` for the numbers; getting the generic types comes down to simply replacing `Maybe` with `m` and `Int` with `a` in all these cases, and adding constraints.

The entire input has type `[Maybe Int]`. The second case pattern-matches this with `(ma:mas)`, picking the first element off the list. So `ma` has the type of the list's element, `Maybe Int`, whereas `mas` is the remainder of the list and thus has type `[Maybe Int]`.

In the do-block, `ma` is unwrapped with the arrow notation, and the result is `a`, whose type is therefore that of `ma` with the monad stripped, i.e. `Int`.

Then, `sequence` is called recursively with the rest of the input, `mas`, which has type `[Maybe Int]`. Substituting into the type of `sequence` shows that the result type is `Maybe [Int]`. This value is again unwrapped, so the target `as` has type `[Int]`.

In the last line, `a` (type `Int`) is prepended to `as` (type `[Int]`), yielding a longer list (`[Int]`). The result is given to `return`, which wraps it in a `Just` (`Maybe [Int]`) to match the result type of `sequence`.

By the way, if you want to track the types through do-blocks in detail, you should first desugar them to normal composition with lambdas.

Comment: Thanks. That makes things much more clear. The fact that `m [t]` for the list monad is `[[t]] ` eluded me until you pointed it out. And I think it helps a bit with my second confusion about the type of `a`. I thought it had to be a monad wrapped value because I couldn't figure out how a Num would combine with a `m [t]` for example, but if  `return []` is essentially `[[]]`, how does `(Num : [[]])` work?

Comment: Extended the answer to hopefully clear up your confusion.